# Javafx SimpleStringProperty deserialization throw IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: java, javafx, serialization

Im developing an application using javafx. I have to save my data in a file. Im using serialization, but since im using SimpleStringProperty i have a problem. 
SimpleStringProperty  isn't serializable so i created the two methods writeObject and readObject. The write method works well (i think, it write in the file) but the read one dont. When i read the save file i got

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data throwed.
```

[image: A class diagram of my data]

Here is the class diagram of my data. What i try to save is Employee.

```
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException
    {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeInt(id);
        s.writeUTF(firstname.get());
        s.writeUTF(lastname.get());
        s.writeUTF(phoneNumber.get());
        s.writeBoolean(gender.get());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        id = s.readInt();
        firstname.set(s.readUTF());
        lastname.set(s.readUTF());
        phoneNumber.set(s.readUTF());
        gender.set(s.readBoolean());
    }
```

Do you have an idea of what could the problem be ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2783)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1605)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at sample.Main.loadData(Main.java:61)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:27)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You will need to show us your stack trace.

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: You use a call to `defaultWriteObject()` but there is no corresponding `defaultReadObject()`.

Comment: Hum that doesn't solve the problem. Here is the new stack trace https://pastebin.com/HTJvm06M

Comment: `s.defaultReadObject();` needs to be the first line of code in your readObject method.

Comment: I tried it but still have an error. The weird thing is that the write is writing in the file, but read dont work. Unread block data mean that i dont read all the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what i was missing is that when calling readObject, the object isn't initialized, so readObject acts like a constructor. All SimpleProperties where null and `firstname.set(s.readUTF());` was throwing a null pointer exception.

Answer (score -1):

You may use normal pojo without javafx properties, 
This may even help you to use frameworks . There are simple work arounds. When they need to be converted to properties. 
However, this is a working example of deserialising javafx properties
https://gist.github.com/james-d/a7202039b00170256293

Comment: I noticed in your exemple that i had to do x1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(...); and not  x1.set(...); Thanks.